WPF application with Touch Not Working Properly
I create application for Windows touch screen, but it's not working properly beacuse when i use mouse click everything works ok but when i use touch sometimes application is working but many times after touch app is freez and do nothing. After this i must touch many times application and it works again maybe for 2 touches, and again freeze.
private void choose_pack_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    touch = true;
    ChoosePack();
}

private void choose_pack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!touch)
        ChoosePack();

    touch = false;
}

When i set in config
<runtime>
<AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Input.Stylus.DisableStylusAndTouchSupport=true" /></runtime>

Everything works greate but scroll in datagrid not working when i touch screen :(.
